# Tabhost inside another tab host

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-style-tabhost

i have a tabhost in my activity. there are 5 tabs and one of these tab contain another tabHost. i need to display my 2nd tabHost under the tabHost.

ie, my tabactivity has 5 tabs.and in my 3rd tab contains another TabHost.

give me any idea of that. this is how i initialize the tabhosts.

```
TabHost mytab;
mytab = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
```

the error displayed in logcat

```
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.netmdapp1/com.example.netmdapp1.PatientSubTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.netmdapp1/com.example.netmdapp1.Appointment}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1487)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at com.example.netmdapp1.PatientGroupActivity.startChildActivity(PatientGroupActivity.java:48)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at com.example.netmdapp1.PatientsCustomView$3.onClick(PatientsCustomView.java:112)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.netmdapp1/com.example.netmdapp1.Appointment}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1487)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:654)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:326)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:216)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at com.example.netmdapp1.PatientSubTabActivity.setupTab(PatientSubTabActivity.java:57)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at com.example.netmdapp1.PatientSubTabActivity.onCreate(PatientSubTabActivity.java:30)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  ... 16 more
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at com.example.netmdapp1.Appointment.onCreate(Appointment.java:88)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-19 10:46:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  ... 26 more

Comment: If you are getting a crash, you should post the stacktrace printed to Logcat. Also, this isn't an answer to your question, but maybe consider an alternate design that doesn't use TabHost within TabHost.

Comment: are you using actionbar tabs?

Comment: can we design like this? tabhost inside a tabhost?? is it possible..

Comment: i think the prob is that the common id for the tabhost.

 mytab = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

Answer (score 0):

`tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);` property decides the default tab. So, if you write `tabHost.setCurrentTab(n);` then **nth** tab will be default tab.

Comment: hi actully what i need that, my ist tabActivity contains 5 tabs. the 3rd tab contains another tabhost. (ie, tabhost under main tabs) but when i run it always crashes